# object pooling framework

Tags: c#, multithreading, object-pooling

any suggestions for a C# object pooling framework?
requirements are multi-thread support and a pool size limit, when a thread requests an object but none is available, it's blocked until one of the other objects is freed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a framework that will do this for you.

You can implement one yourself with a trivial amount of code though. (1 class, ~20 lines of code)

Have a look at the MSDN article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/toub/archive/2006/04/12/blocking-queues.aspx)

Comment: in .Net 4.0 take a look at the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace, many of these are now in the box.

Answer (score 0):

Try the enterprise services namespace:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enterpriseservices.aspx

Depending on what you need, this may do the trick for you.